# How to get union type from types of values of type in typescript

Tags: typescript

There is a type

```
type A = { a: type1; b: type2; c: type2 };
```

How to create a type, which creates union type from possible value types of type A?

```
type Magic<A>; // type1 | type2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the union of all type values in a type:

```
type Magic<T> = T[keyof T];
// Magic<A> has type: type1 | type2
```

Or, if you want to only get the types from specific keys:

```
type Magic<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K];
// Magic<A, "a"|"b"> has type: type1 | type2
```

Take a look at the mapped types section of [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mappedtypes) to see how those kinds of types work.

Comment: Don't think you really need the `Pick`, `type Magic<T> = T[keyof T];` should work just as well

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!